# Define Control+Shift keys without kbd

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to add some functionality to someone else's package, and so
I'd like to respect their patterns. Unfortunately, one of these
patterns is to not use `kbd`.

I need to bind a function to `C-S-b`, but I can't figure out how. I
know how to do this with a single modifier (e.g. `"\S-b"`), but I
can't get it to work with multiple modifiers. 
I know I can just
evaluate `(kbd "C-S-b")` and use its output (`[33554434]`), but I'd
like something easier to read.

Here are a few things I've tried:

```
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
  "\C-\S-b" 'test-command)
;;; Invalid modifier

(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
  [C-S-b] 'test-command)
;;; Does nothing

(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map
  "\C-B" 'test-command)
;;; Binds C-b
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing a `?` and two backslashes in the vector representation:

```el
(global-set-key [?\C-\S-b] 'test-command)
```

The section on [Key Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html) in the Elisp manual says:

> Key sequences containing function keys, mouse button events, system
>   events, or non-ASCII characters such as `C-=` or `H-a` cannot be
>   represented as strings; they have to be represented as vectors.
>
> In the vector representation, each element of the vector represents
>   an input event, **in its Lisp form**. For example, the vector `[?\C-x ?l]` represents the key sequence `C-x l`.

And under [Other Character Modifier Bits](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Other-Char-Bits.html) it says:

> The Lisp syntax for the shift bit is `\S-`; thus, `?\C-\S-o` or `?\C-\S-O` represents the shifted-control-o character.

Comment: I had been trying to understand what the question marks mean. Thanks to your reply, I found these: [Ctl-Char Syntax ?\C-](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Ctl_002dChar-Syntax.html) and [Meta-Char Syntax ?\M-](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Meta_002dChar-Syntax.html)

Comment: And yes, Malabarba's question is answered in this page on [Other Modifier Bits](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Other-Char-Bits.html).

Comment: @kaushalmodi Thanks for the links! They're very useful in gaining a deeper understanding of what's going on.